# Autoclass in R/Python?

Tags: r, clustering, python

Are there any packages that implement the Autoclass/ Naive Bayes Clustering algorithm in R or Python?

Alternatively, what are some other clustering algorithms that can handle both categorical and numeric variables that are implemented in either R or Python?

Comment: Be aware that asking for code or packages is off-topic for CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))--you may or may not get a response about that. Your 2nd question is on-topic, but perhaps a bit broad. Can you add some details / constraints, or otherwise focus it a little?

Answer (score 1):

In R:

```
install.packages("e1071")
library(e1071) 
?naiveBayes
```